# How to connecto to Centos linux from Windows XP?

Tags: linux, centos, remote-desktop

We are currently trying to establish a remote desktop connection to Centos Linux from Windows XP device. We searched on the Internet and found out that there are multiple ways of doing so through TightVNC and NX Client for Windows.

However it seems we're doing some in-correct configuration on Centos server. Perhaps, the command that we've written is wrong. Can somebody guide us through a step-by-step procedure of establishing rdp connection on Centos from Windows XP machine.

Any help/input through links is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You do not do rdp to CentOS. You basically either do X over SSH, VNC or NX, but no rdp.

For X over SSH:

1. install an X server on your Windows machine
2. connect to the CentOS machine with putty and the -X option
3. run an application

For VNC:

1. Install a VNC server on the CentOS machine
2. connect with a VNC client on the Windows XP machine
3. More info [here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server)

For NX:

1. Install the NX server on the CentOS machine
2. connect to the CentOS machine with the NX client
3. More info [here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/FreeNX)

Comment: For X over SSH, you also need to have a local X server running on the Windows machine.  Look up Xming, it's free and easy to use.